# How to give dynamic height for vertical line

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have been designing following UI page
[image]

I have completed most of it.
[image]

I am not able to get vertical line between dates, month which are there on the left side.

I tried to use following style

```
        .Line-Copy {
             width: 1px;
             height: 347px;
             opacity: 0.5;
             border: solid 1px #000000;
         }
```

As height is fixed its not working.
I am looping through the data and
Dates are displayed as div

```
                   <div className="row">
                          <div className="nh-day">{moment(value.noteCreationDate).date()}</div>
                    <div/>
```

Can someone suggest how can I solve this dynamic height vertical line issue ?

Thank you in advance

Adding complete code snippet here

```
          <div>
          <div style={{ paddingLeft: "135px" }}>
                {this.displaySelectedNote()}
              </div>
              {this.state.allCustomerNotes.map((value, index) => {
                return this.state.selectedDisplayNote == value.noteTypeId ||
                  (this.state.selectedDisplayNote == "all" &&
                    this.state.totalCount > 0) ? (
                  <div>
                    <div className="nh-year">
                      {index == 0 ||
                      (index > 0 &&
                        moment(value.noteCreationDate).year() !=
                          moment(
                            this.state.allCustomerNotes[index - 1]
                              .noteCreationDate
                          ).year()) ? (
                        <div>{moment(value.noteCreationDate).year()}</div>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <div className="nh-month">
                      {index == 0 ||
                      (index > 0 &&
                        moment(value.noteCreationDate).month() !=
                          moment(
                            this.state.allCustomerNotes[index - 1]
                              .noteCreationDate
                          ).month()) ? (
                        <div>{moment(value.noteCreationDate).month()}</div>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      {index == 0 ||
                      (index > 0 &&
                        moment(value.noteCreationDate).date() !=
                          moment(
                            this.state.allCustomerNotes[index - 1]
                              .noteCreationDate
                          ).date()) ? (
                        <div className="row">
                          <div className="nh-day">{moment(value.noteCreationDate).date()}</div>
                          <div/>
                          
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <div className="nh-date-and-time">
                            {moment(value.noteCreationDate).format("hh:mm a")}
                          </div>
                    <div className="nh-tiles">
                      <span
                        className={
                          value.noteType.includes("CS")
                            ? "CS"
                            : value.noteType.includes("Important ")
                            ? "notes-history-important"
                            : "RG"
                        }
                      >
                        <img
                          alt=""
                          src={
                            value.noteType.includes("CS ")
                              ? "/assets/images/notes/agent.png"
                              : value.noteType.includes("Important ")
                              ? "/assets/images/notes/ball.png"
                              : value.noteType.includes("Loyalty ")
                              ? "/assets/images/notes/loyalty.png"
                              : value.noteType.includes("Responsible Gaming ")
                              ? "/assets/images/notes/rg.png"
                              : value.noteType.includes("Legal")
                              ? "/assets/images/notes/legal.png"
                              : ""
                          }
                          className="notes-history-ball-body"
                        ></img>
                        &nbsp;
                        {value.noteType}
                      </span>
                      <div className="nh-splitter" />
                      <span className="Note-Copy">{value.playerNotes}</span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  ""
                );
              })}
          </div>
```

Comment: Depending on how it's laid out, you could just add a border to the left of a container element that wraps everything on a certain date.

Comment: put the code here so we know how you structure you html and css

Comment: What is the structure of the parents? As DBS say you could solve it by adding something to the parent, I would suggest a psuedo (before, after) element with position absolute rather then border though.

Answer (score 0):

I would structure this like you can see in the picture - every color is another level of hierarchy.
So the purple square - main parent of the date (which day). The purple parent has two green children - one with the numer and a vertical line and second with the hours etc.
A green div with a vertical line and a number should be attached to the top. The div with a number within should be attached to the top also. A div with a vertical line should have it's height set to 100%.

Purple parent's height should depend of the height of it's elements.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Aleks. I tried it and looking  https://ibb.co/jDvGHNV . Here line between month is missing . I tried to include that in purple div still not working.

Comment: Can you make a codepen/Stackblitz example of  your problem. It would be helpful. I'd try to fix the code there.